# How to make my python code loop back

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm really new to python and I'm attempting to learn by making a simple game. I want the user to be able to input their action, then if they chose not too continue, they will be sent back to the stage of inputting again. I've attempted this as best I can but once they choose not to "continue", they can no longer choose any of the other options I've set out.

Help is appreciated.

```
print ("How do you proceed?")
print ("Do you Shout? Look? Continue?")
action1 = input()

if action1 == ("Continue"): #Continue to next section
    print ("You continue on throught the darkness untill you reach a cold stone wall")
    pass

elif action1 == "Shout":
    print ("In the dark noone can hear you scream.")

elif action1 == ('Look'):
    print ("'I cannae see anything in the dark' you think to yourself in a braod Scottish accent.")

while action1 != ("Continue"):
    print ("Enter your next action.(Case sensitive!!)")
    print ("Shout? Look? Continue?")
    action1 = input() #Want this too loop back to start of action menu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the whole process into one `while` loop and break out of the loop if the user input is valid:

```
print("How do you proceed?") 

while True:          
    print("Do you Shout? Look? Continue?")
    action1 = input()

    if action1 == "Continue": # Continue to next section
        print("You continue on throught the darkness untill you reach a cold stone wall")
        break # break out of the while loop

    elif action1 == "Shout":
        print("In the dark none can hear you scream.")

    elif action1 == 'Look':
        print("'I cannot see anything in the dark' you think to yourself in a broad Scottish accent.")

    print("Enter your next action.(Case sensitive!!)")

# You'll land here after the break statement
```